# react-native-fbsdk, Can't use AppEventsLogger on android

Tags: android, react-native

Using "react": "15.3.2", "react-native": "0.35.0", "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.3.0"
the android virtual Devices I use is => Android 7.0, API Level: 24

I have followed the Readme setting https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

I want to use Analytics for Apps.

On iOS it works well both on App Launches and AppEventsLogger

On Android it works well on App Launches, and I could got the data on facebook analytics website

but about the AppEventsLogger.logPurchase or AppEventsLogger.logEvent, I will got failed msg

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  AppEventsLogger,
} = FBSDK;
AppEventsLogger.logPurchase(15, 'USD', {'param': 'value'})
```

but I got the error like this

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.logPurchase(java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Currency, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
logPurchase
    FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:175
invoke
    Method.java:-2
```

do other people have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the AppEventLogger object is not initialized..
Do you set up the facebook android sdk correctly? Are other features in the react-native-fbsdk works for you, e.g Login, Like?

Comment: I works well on Login. just use the sample code,
only AppEventLogger can't work

Comment: I can't repro it in my app. Can you file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs? From there you can secure-upload a sample app that reproduces the bug for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I try call it after the component is mounted, and it works

like this

```
    export default class FbTest extends Component {

      componentDidMount() {
          AppEventsLogger.logPurchase(20, 'USD', {'param': 'testlala'});
      }
```